# Analytic functions and plain SQL equivalent

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle and SQL Developer. I have downloaded HR schema and need to do some queries with it. Now I'm working with table `Employees`. As an user I need to see the list of employees with lowest salary in each department. I need to provide different solutions by means of plain SQL and one of analytic functions. About analytic functions, I have used `RANK()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT
         employee_id,
         first_name,
         department_id,
         salary,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department_id 
                      ORDER BY salary) result
     FROM
         employees)
WHERE 
    result = 1 
    AND department_id IS NOT NULL;
```

The result seems correct:

[image: Result]

but when I try to use plain SQL I actually get all employees with their salaries.

Here is my attempt with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    department_id, MIN(salary) AS "Lowest salary"
FROM 
    employees
GROUP BY 
    department_id;
```

This code seems good, but I need to also get columns `first_name` and `employee_id`.

I tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    department_id,
    MIN(salary) result
FROM
    employees
GROUP BY
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    department_id;
```

and this:

```
SELECT
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    salary,
    departments.department_id
FROM
    employees
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    departments ON (employees.department_id = departments.department_id)
WHERE
    employees.salary = (SELECT MIN(salary)
                        FROM departments 
                        WHERE department_id = employees.department_id)
```

These seem wrong. How can I change or modify my queries to get the same result as when I'm using `RANK()` by means of plain SQL (two solutions at least)?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this, but as your are probably interested in what is wrong with the two queries you tried: In the first one you select the minimum salary per employee (because of `GROUP BY employee_id`), and this is not at all what you want. In the second query you join to departments, which is not necessary, because the departments table has no information that helps solve the task. In the subquery you select from the department table, but access `MIN(salary)`. The department table has no salary, so what you are selecting is actually the salary of the employee in the main query.

Comment: To elaborate the second case further: In `WHERE` you are looking at one employee at a time. The subquery will select one department row, because of `WHERE department_id = employees.department_id` (Provided the departments table *has* a column called department_id, for otherwise your where clause is `WHERE employees.department_id = employees.department_id` for the lack of any other possibility.) You select the salary, and as there is no salary in the departments table (`departments.salary` would raise an error, this is `employee.salary`. `MIN` of one value is the value itself, so ...

Comment: ... you compare the employee's salary with itself: `employees.salary = (SELECT MIN(employees.salary) FROM whatever)` is the same as `employees.salary = employees.salary`. So, when using multiple tables in a query, always qualify your columns with their table name. For readability you can use table aliases: `WHERE
e.salary = (SELECT MIN(d.salary) FROM departments d WHERE d.department_id = e.department_id)`. This would result in a syntax error at `d.salary`, and you'd see your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options could be like here  (with old EMP table)...

```sql
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, DEPTNO, SAL
FROM   EMP e
WHERE  SAL = (Select MIN_SAL From (SELECT DEPTNO, Min(SAL) "MIN_SAL"
                                    FROM   EMP
                                    GROUP BY DEPTNO) 
              Where DEPTNO = e.DEPTNO)
ORDER BY DEPTNO, SAL;
```

Second option could be...

```sql
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, DEPTNO, SAL
FROM   (SELECT e.EMPNO, e.ENAME, e.DEPTNO, e. SAL, (Select Min(SAL) "MIN_SAL" From EMP Where DEPTNO = e.DEPTNO) "MIN_SAL" From EMP e) 
WHERE  SAL = MIN_SAL
ORDER BY DEPTNO, SAL;
```

Regards...

Comment: Thank you for help! One more question: if i only need one person per department with lowest salary, how can I modify code? I mean in department 90, we have two people with same salary, I want to receive only one.

Comment: @Andy - it depends which one of those two you want. It could be the one with bigger or smaller EMPNO, with Min Or Max of ENAME or the one who has earlier or later HIREDATE. If the question is to get a list of emps with smallest salary per department and if two of them have the same (smallest) salary then both of them should be listed, just as they are. Regards...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to find the lowest salary per employee and use the main query to only show the information of those employees that are selected by this subquery:

```
SELECT 
employee_id,
first_name,
department_id,
salary
FROM employees e1
WHERE salary =
(SELECT MIN(e2.salary)
FROM employees e2
WHERE e1.employee_id = e2.employee_id);
```

This will produce exactly the same outcome as your query with `RANK`.

I think it would make sense to apply some sorting which is missing in your query. I don't know how you want to sort, but here an example to sort by the employee's name:

```
SELECT 
employee_id,
first_name,
department_id,
salary
FROM employees e1
WHERE salary =
(SELECT MIN(e2.salary)
FROM employees e2
WHERE e1.employee_id = e2.employee_id)
ORDER BY first_name;
```

Since you asked for at least two solutions, let's have a look on another option:

```
SELECT 
e1.employee_id,
e1.first_name,
e1.department_id,
e1.salary
FROM employees e1
JOIN (
SELECT employee_id, MIN(salary) salary
FROM employees
GROUP BY employee_id ) e2
ON e1.employee_id = e2.employee_id AND e1.salary = e2.salary
ORDER BY first_name;
```

As you can see, this differs since the sub query will apply a `GROUP BY` clause and it can be successfully executed as own query which is not possible for the sub query used in the previous query.

The `JOIN` to the main query will then make sure to get again the desired result.

Comment: Your examples work the same as this query: `SELECT
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    department_id,
    MIN(salary) result
FROM
    employees
GROUP BY
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    department_id;`, thank you for explanation, but i need exactly the result that is shown in picture.

Comment: No, that's not correct. My queries will produce the correct result, i.e. the same outcome like the query with RANK, while the query you mentioned in your comment doesn't. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/r67u7_Ei

Comment: Here is the result i receive in SQL Developer: 107 rows with all employees with their salaries.  I just can't paste here an image, so i don't know what to say. Your example shows right result in dbfiddle.

Comment: Well, if you get 107 employees with their lowest salary, this just means that you have such many employees that satisfy the condition "lowest salary per department". You have many departments or many employees per department with the same lowest salary. The fiddle shows the queries work correctly. So if you don't like the results of those correct queries, the conditions you explained us are incorrect.

Comment: I see that you provide good answer and explanation, but the reality is that I receive salaries for departments for all employees. I see that fiddle shows the queries work correctly. However, in SQL Developer the result is different. I mean it's quite interesting and I try to understand what the issue can be. I suggest you to try in real your queries in SQL Developer with HR schema in order to see the result by own eyes or maybe use Live SQL Oracle to see that there happens something strange. Anyway, I appreciate your effort and your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options to get the employees with the minimum salary in their department:

### With MIN (salary) OVER (...)

```
select employee_id, first_name, department_id, salary
from
(
  select e.*, min(salary) over (partition by department_id) as min_sal
  from employees e
)
where sal = min_sal;
```

### With RANK and FETCH FIRST

```
select *
from employees
order by rank() over (partition by department_id order by salary)
fetch first row with ties;
```

### With IN

```
select *
from employees
where (department_id, salary) in
(
  select department_id, min(salary)
  from employees
  group by department_id
);
```

### With NOT EXISTS

```
select *
from employees e
where not exists
(
  select null
  from employees other
  where other.department_id = e.department_id
  and other.salary < e.salary
);
```

Comment: Thank you for help! One more question: if i only need one person per department with lowest salary, how can I modify code? I mean in department 90, we have two people with same salary, I want to receive only one.

Comment: Well, this is a big change. The first query would be inappropriate for this. In the second query you'd replace `RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`. The third query is again inappropriate for this altered task. And in the fourth query you'd replace and `other.salary < e.salary` by `and (other.salary < e.salary or (other.salary = e.salary and other.employee_id < e.employee_id))` in the subquery. For this rare scenario where you want to pick one of the lowest paid employees per department arbitrarily instead of just showing all, Oracle's `KEEP FIRST/LAST` would be a great choice, too.

Comment: But as mentioned, this already is another request. You were looking for queries that produce the same result as your `RANK` query. You should hence accept one of the answers you got.

Answer (score 1):

If you will only ever have one person with the minimum salary per department then you can use `KEEP`:

```sql
SELECT department_id,
       MIN(employee_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY salary) AS employee_id,
       MIN(first_name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY salary, employee_id) AS first_name,
       MIN(salary) AS min_salary
FROM   employees
GROUP BY department_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, department_id, first_name, salary) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'Alice', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'Betty', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 'Carol', 3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'Debra', 3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, 'Emily', 4000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DEPARTMENT_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | MIN_SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Alice | 1000 |
| 2 | 3 | Carol | 3000 |

*Note: this will not match Debra, even though she also has the lowest salary in department 2, as it will only find a single employee with the minimum salary and the minimum employee id.*

---

If you can have multiple employees with the same minimum-per-department then you can use a correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT department_id,
       employee_id,
       first_name,
       salary
FROM   employees e
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   employees x
         WHERE  e.department_id = x.department_id
         HAVING MIN(x.salary) = e.salary
       );
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| DEPARTMENT_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Alice | 1000 |
| 2 | 3 | Carol | 3000 |
| 2 | 4 | Debra | 3000 |

Which does return Debra.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PVF0Tq4l)

Comment: Thank you for help! One more question: if i only need one person per department with lowest salary, how can I modify code? I mean in department 90, we have two people with same salary, I want to receive only one.